# using time.sleep in wxPython

Tags: python, user-interface, wxpython

Using time.sleep in my wxPython code just after re-positioning a bitmapbutton caused my button to go totally blank. Just a white space was left in the region where the button should have been. Can any one please explain the reason and suggest any solution? Here's my code:

```
import wx
import time
class gui(wx.Frame):
  def __init__(self,parent,id):
    wx.Frame.__init__(self,parent,id,'New Window',pos=(0,0),size=wx.DisplaySize())
    panel=wx.Panel(self)
    self.SetBackGroundColour('green')
    self.pic=wx.BitmapButton(self,-1,wx.Image("Candle.jpg",wx.BITMAP_TYPE_ANY).ConvertToBitmap(),pos=(700,300))
    self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON,self.position,self.pic)
  def positon(self,event):
    self.pic.Hide()
    self.pic=wx.BitmapButton(self,-1,wx.Image("Candle.jpg",wx.BITMAP_TYPE_ANY).ConvertToBitmap(),pos=(700,300))
    time.sleep(2)
    self.pic.Hide()
if __name__=='__main__':
  app=wx.PySimpleApp()
  frame=gui(None,-1)
  frame.Show()
  app.MainLoop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

time.sleep() blocks wx's mainloop and makes the GUI unresponsive for however long you've told it to sleep. There are several alternatives. You can use a [wx.Timer](http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2009/08/25/wxpython-using-wx-timers/) or use [threads](http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2010/05/22/wxpython-and-threads/) (or similar). I think using a Timer makes more sense in your use case though.

Comment: Thank you so very much. I solved the problem later using wx.CallLater but I was looking for a reason as to why the image goes blank. You provided it so thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

Well there's no wonder your button goes blank, you've pretty much programmed it to do so.

```
    self.pic.Hide() => hides the button
 self.pic=wx.BitmapButton(self,-1,wx.Image("Candle.jpg",wx.BITMAP_TYPE_ANY).ConvertToBitmap(),pos=(700,300)) => displays the button once again
    time.sleep(2) => takes a brake for 2 seconds
    self.pic.Hide() => hides the button again
```

The conclusion is, your button won't show up. So I don't see what's the problem, as it does exactly what you programmed it to.

Comment: I did not get you. After the button was displayed isn't it supposed to be there till I hide it again, which I do after 2 seconds.

Comment: untill it hides by himself. After you press the button it hides, shows out again and stays for 2 secs and hides again.

Comment: But how do you explain the image going blank. It is supposed to show the image for 2 seconds, right? I solved the problem using wx.CallLater but I would still like to know the reason behind this.

Answer (score 0):

well it depends, was time sleep used in the button's event ?, cause I believe if it was it's because of that. The button waits for the event it triggered to end so it would go back to its initial state.

Comment: Well yes time.sleep was indeed in the button's event. I have added the code now. Can you suggest any ways to get rid of it. I am an absolute novice in this field and am clueless as to how to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

`sleep` is blocking, so execution is stuck in your position method for two seconds and is unable to return to the MainLoop to process other events, like painting your changes to the screen. After the two seconds are up the image is hidden, but was never drawn.

To get the effect you want you'll have to start a timer, and bind the timer to a handler which can show the `StaticBitmap` again.

By the way you can also call `Show` again rather than creating a new control, and it's parent should also be the panel, not the frame.