# WXPYTHON tricky

Tags: multithreading, button, while-loop, wxpython

I have a textctrl box - I am reading data from it continuously every 1 second. I have a button which have to be enabled when the value drops below 50. I have a piece of code, which is making the GUI irresponsive. In the code I am presenting here, I am waiting until the value is less than 50. Then Enabling the start button

```
    while self.pressure_text_control.GetValue()>50:
        self.start.Disable()
        time.sleep(1)
    self.start.Enable()
```

This whole code is inside an another button event.

```
   def OnDone(self, event):
        self.WriteToControllerButton([0x04])
        self.status_text.SetLabel('PRESSURE CALIBRATION DONE \n DUMP PRESSURE')
        self.led1.SetBackgroundColour('GREY')
        self.done.Disable()
        self.add_pressure.Disable()
        while self.pressure_text_control.GetValue()>50:
            self.start.Disable()
            time.sleep(1)
        self.start.Enable()
```

The value in pressure_text_control is getting updated every 1 second.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [using time.sleep in wxPython](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11377316/using-time-sleep-in-wxpython)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set up a `wx.timer` to do the work for you, this will free up the GUI main-loop i.e. make it responsive.
The wx.Timer class allows you to execute code at specified intervals.
https://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/wx.Timer.html

```
    self.timer = wx.Timer(self)
    self.Bind(wx.EVT_TIMER, self.OnTimer, self.timer)
    self.timer.Start(1000)

def OnTimer(self, event):
    "Check the value of self.pressure_text_control here and do whatever"
```

Don't forget to `self.timer.Stop()` before closing the program.

Comment: Does this keep checking the value until the timer is ON? How can I exit once the value is less than 50 as I require. Does not the self.timer.Start(1000) mean it starts after 1 second? AND NOT IT RUNS EVERY 1 SECOND

Comment: I provided a link that explains what wx.timer does. `Start(1000)` essentially means that it runs every second. So yes, it starts after 1 second and then runs every 1 second after that, until stopped. If your require the timer to stop at any time execute the `self.timer.Stop()` command, as mentioned. You can always set it running again, when required, with `self.timer.Start(1000)`